# NoSuchMethodError setDecorFitsSystemWindows when I use window?.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(true)

Tags: android, statusbar, android-statusbar, android-window

I want to make my Activity top to the screen, and the `StatusBar` transparent, so I write this code:

```
window?.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(true)
window?.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
```

My targetVersion is 30
My appcompat version is 1.3.0

but when I run it , I got Exception like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtZVN.png)

Comment: Try this one `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, true)`... Also please add the full stacktrace as a text not an image.

Comment: thanks, it works, and also thank you for you suggestion

Answer (score 0):

So, to remove this exception you need to use the compatible version of the window (i.e. `WindowCompat`)

So replace:

```
window?.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(true)
```

With:

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, true)
```